# Comparing an empirical equation to tabulated data

Tags: algebra-precalculus, linear-regression

I have a multivariable exponential function (Y=kA^aB^b...) that I would like to compare to tabulated data that is supposed to be represented by the equation. I want to show that the equation is accurate in relative terms because determining k is not necessary, it's just the accuracy of the exponents that I am interested in.

One way I thought of doing it is dividing Y(x2)/Y(x1) per variable and comparing the jumps as per the equation to the jumps in the equation. Is there a more accurate way of doing this.

Thank you

Moustafa

Comment: You could use non-linear regression to see if the exponential function fits the data.  It's based on all the partial derivatives of $Y$ w.r.t. each parameter on the right side.

Comment: You can logarithmize the function and then apply linear regression: $\ln(y)=\ln (k)+a\cdot \ln(A)+b\cdot \ln(B)+...$